# EditText width not taking effect Android

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have the following XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:text="40"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />
```

I would like to set a specific width or a max width would also do the trick (not working either). The text field is going from the vertical centre to the far right and I would like it to position from vertical centre to 20p to the right.
When I set max_width or width it doesn't seem to take any effect. It makes no difference what I put in.

Any idea why? Thanks for an answers.

Below is a screen shot of the activity followed by all the XML Code:

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"



        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rB2"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rB1"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioGroup" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:autoText="false"
            android:text="40"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:width="20dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/tV1"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="112dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/result"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/explan"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/et1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="73dp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5% bonus"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton4"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton4" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="10% bonus"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show the screen shot of your activity page

Comment: I have added screenshot

Comment: try to remove width that you specified 20 dp and set layout_width to match_ parent

Comment: No difference unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `match_parent`
or you can also manually set width such as `"50dp"` or `"100dp"`

Comment: Setting it to match_parent doesn't seem to make a difference either

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code may it help you, othervise please give us your full xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"



android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="rB2"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="rB1"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/radioGroup" />
</RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mylinearforedittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:id="@+id/et11"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:text="40"
        android:ems="10"
        android:width="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:text="40"
    android:ems="10"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="tV1"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="result"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="explan"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mylinearforedittext"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5% bonus"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/radioButton4" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10% bonus"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it. But the positions of all objects seem to be changed now. Possibly given the fact that they are relative.

Comment: You have just now drag and drop and give up some margin for your view you can do it on your XML Design mode .

Answer (score 0):

Have you undertaken these instructions?

```
fill_parent/match_parent
```

---

```
android:gravity /layoutgravity
```

```xml
<EditText
    android:text="40"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" //imp :can use fill_parent too

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:autoText="false"
    android:layout_margin="150dp"  //use whichever dp you want


    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: This works, however it is no longer centred  vertically in screen

Answer (score 0):

You're using :     `android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup2"` in the EditText which means that your text views starts from where your radioGroup2 starts which is from the middle of the screen.

You'll need to remove this line.

Comment: I believe the end of the EditText objects lies at the end of "Input the mark..." string. I can only set the end of the EditText object relative to some other object, but not relative to the screen width. If this is possible it should solve my problem